# Im trying to get the lenght of of my captions but its saying .lenght undefined and its returning the lenght when i log it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

> This is where im calling the caption, caption is a prop btw that im passing to another component

```
///i passed caption here as a prop
const PostsHeader = ({ image, username, postimage, caption }) => {
  ///number of likes
  const likes = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 200);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Div>
        <Left>
          <Img
            style={{
              backgroundImage: `url(${require(`../../img/${image}`)})`,
            }}
          />
          <UName>{username}</UName>
        </Left>
        <Right>
          <UilEllipsisH size={20} style={{ marginRight: 10, marginTop: 10 }} />
        </Right>
      </Div>
      <PostImg
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${require(`../../img/${postimage}`)})`,
        }}
      />
      <Icons>
        <LeftIcons>
          <UilHeart size={22} style={{ marginRight: 10, cursor: "pointer" }} />
          <UilComment
            size={22}
            style={{ marginRight: 10, cursor: "pointer" }}
          />
          <UilMessage
            size={22}
            style={{ marginRight: 10, cursor: "pointer" }}
          />
        </LeftIcons>
        <RightIcons>
          <UilBookmarkFull
            size={22}
            style={{ marginRight: 3, cursor: "pointer" }}
          />
        </RightIcons>
      </Icons>
      <Likes>{likes} Likes</Likes>
   //comment, this is where im using the caption
      <Caption>
        <b style={{ fontWeight: 600, paddingRight: 5 }}>Tommyk</b>
        {caption.length > 61 ? caption.slice(0, 61) + "..." : caption}
      </Caption>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default PostsHeader;
```

> This is where i have my captions array and where im using the caption prop

```
const Posts = () => {
  const captions = [
    "Whatever is good for your soul, do that Whatever is good for your soul, do that",
    "Even the stars were jealous of the sparkle in her eyes",
    "Stress less and enjoy the best",
    "Get out there and live a little",
    "I’m not high maintenance, you’re just low effort",
    "I’m not gonna sugar coat the truth, I’m not Willy Wonka",
    "Life is better when you’re laughing",
    "Look for the magic in every moment",
    "Vodka may not be the answer but it’s worth a shot",
    "A sass a day keeps the basics away",
  ];
  console.log(captions[0].length);
  return (
    <Container>
      <PostsHeaderAndBody
        image="tk.jpg"
        username="The.tommyk"
        postimage="back.jpg"
        caption={captions[0]}
      />
 </Container>
  );
};

export default Posts;
```

> The problem now is `{caption.length > 61 ? caption.slice(0, 61) + "..." : caption}` is sayinng undefined but if i `console.log(captions[0].length);` it logs the lenght of the caption soo i dont know why caption.length is undefined, please help

Comment: `caption` or `captions` ? Can you show the `captions` definition.

Comment: caption is the prop name and captions is the name of the array

Comment: Can you share the code of your Caption Component?

Comment: i have edited the code so you can see the full code

Comment: will be cool if you can put them in codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

> I have solved the problem already. The problem was i added apostrophes as in ' which is not allowed apparently

> Instead of this, ```
> const captions = [
> "Whatever is good for your soul, do that Whatever is good for your soul, do that",
> "Even the stars were jealous of the sparkle in her eyes",
> "Stress less and enjoy the best",
> "Get out there and live a little",
> "I’m not high maintenance, you’re just low effort",
> "I’m not gonna sugar coat the truth, I’m not Willy Wonka",
> "Life is better when you’re laughing",
> "Look for the magic in every moment",
> "Vodka may not be the answer but it’s worth a shot",
> "A sass a day keeps the basics away",
> ];

````
>I removed the apostrophes like this ```const captions = [
    "Whatever is good for your soul, do that Whatever is good for your soul, do that",
    "Even the stars were jealous of the sparkle in her eyes",
    "Stress less and enjoy the best",
    "Get out there and live a little",
    "Im not high maintenance, youre just low effort",
    "Im not gonna sugar coat the truth, Im not Willy Wonka",
    "Life is better when youre laughing",
    "Look for the magic in every moment",
    "Vodka may not be the answer but its worth a shot",
    "A sass a day keeps the basics away",
  ];
````